# How do i know the current post type when on post.php in admin?

Tags: plugins, admin, post-type

Im trying to do something with an admin_init hook if - and only if - the user is editing a post (post.php) with post type "event". My problem is that, even though wordpress points to a global variable calls $post_type. if i do:

```
global $post_type;
var_dump($post_type);
```

It returns NULL.

but if I do this:

```
global $pagenow;
var_dump($pagenow);
```

it returns my current page. i.e. "post.php".

I looked into this function `$screen = get_current_screen();` but thats not declared until after the admin_init hooks has run, and then its to late.

So my question is, how do I, by the time admin_init is run, find out what post type the current post being edited is. if the url is `post.php?post=81&action=edit` then, how do I know what post type postid=81 is?

Thanks
Malthe

Comment: what about `global $post`?

Comment: global post is not available in the admin_init hook yet

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'do_something_152677' );
function do_something_152677 () {
    // Global object containing current admin page
    global $pagenow;

    // If current page is post.php and post isset than query for its post type 
    // if the post type is 'event' do something
    if ( 'post.php' === $pagenow && isset($_GET['post']) && 'post' === get_post_type( $_GET['post'] ) )
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: When editing an existing post the url is '/wp-admin/post.php?post=81&action=edit'

Comment: Allright fixed now... even though you have to query the db to do so...

Comment: Please add an explanation to what your code does

Comment: A very helpfull answer even in 2018!

Comment: Code only answers are not very useful.  See @PieterGoosen commment above, from ~5 years ago....

Answer (score 6):

`get_current_screen()->post_type` holds post type slug.
Or `$_REQUEST['post_type']`.
Note that for standard pages/posts post_type might not be set.

Answer (score 3):

I am going to expand on MiCc83's answer. There are a few things that don't follow the OP's original questions but overall it's a great solution. For example, it would not work with a post_type event because you are checking the post_type as 'post' in the answer.

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'do_something_152677' );
function do_something_152677 () {
    // Global object containing current admin page
    global $pagenow;

    // If current page is post.php and post isset than query for its post type 
    if ( 'post.php' === $pagenow && isset($_GET['post']) ){
        $post_id = $_GET['post'];

        // Do something with $post_id. For example, you can get the full post object:
        $post = get_post($post_id);

    }
}
```

The condition `'post' === get_post_type( $_GET['post'] )` in the previous answer would prevent this from working on a post type 'event'. You would need to check for post type 'event' instead of 'post'.

Comment: This is a complete and working answer.